# ANOVA and LSD grouping in R when mean and variance is given

Tags: r, statistics, anova

I have the following data.

```
Strain  n   mean    variance
A       8     75          18
B       8     70          23
C       8     72          21
D       8     78          20
```

I want to calculate their ANOVA and LSD grouping in R.
I know the simple way of calculating ANOVA and LSD test when value of each sample and each treatment is given. but I am unable to do it when only mean and variance or standard deviation is given.